# Codeigniter room booking form validation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation

I'm trying to make a form for booking a room using `form_validation` to validate whether the room is already booked or not when user input the data into the form. I showed the output into table. Here's my validation:

```
function add_room()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('start', 'Start Date', 'required|is_unique[calendar.start]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_t', 'Start Time', 'required|is_unique[calendar.start_t]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('end_t', 'End Time', 'required|is_unique[calendar.end_t]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('room', 'Room', 'required|is_unique[calendar.room]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'NRP', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ext', 'EXT', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('topic', 'Topic', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('attend', 'Attendees', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->form_validation->run('start_t');
    }
    elseif ($this->form_validation->run('start_t') == TRUE) {
        $this->form_validation->run('end_t');
    }
    elseif ($this->form_validation->run('end_t') == TRUE) {
        $this->form_validation->run('start');
    }
    elseif ($this->form_validation->run('start') == TRUE) {
        $this->form_validation->run('room');
    }
    elseif ($this->form_validation->run('room') == TRUE) {
        $this->form_validation->run();
    }
    elseif ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $this->calendar->add_room();
    } else {
        validation_errors();
        $this->conf->msg('danger');
    }
    redirect('calendar/meeting');


}
```

I know my code is awful, I'm still not sure how to make the `if` structure. I want the validation check whether if the `Room` at the `Start Time`,`End Time` and `Start Date` is already booked or not. If it's already booked the validation would be false and showing `error message`. I'm not really good at `CI`. In fact, I'm new in this programming stuff. So, how can I make a proper booking room in `CI`? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the errors that you want to validate in an array

$config = array(
             array('field' => 'bk_r_type_id', 'label' => 'bk_r_type_id Name', 'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]')
        );

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

Comment: Kay: Can I make a few `is_unique` in one 'rules'. It seems that my field (`room`,`start`,`start_t`,`end_t`) is have to be related to the other.

Comment: yes . u can . Trying two types of validation make your code more secure. First one is trying form validation . Second one is validating data before inserting to database

Comment: No, I mean make more than one `is_unique` like: 'rules' => 'required|is_unique[calendar.room]|is_unique[calendar.start]|is_unique[calendar.start_t]|is_unique[calendar.end_t]'. So the validation check each field, its a booking system.